# Get function only from the inner html in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Through this:

```
var all = $("#innerhtml").map(function() {
            return this.innerHTML;
        }).get();
        alert(all);
```

I find:

```
<a class="cart-btn remove text-muted small" onclick="removeCart('fgh', 'ser');"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></a>
<a class="name-image" >
<span class="name">
    <span class="quantity">28 × </span>rum ‘n’ beat</span>
</a>
<p class="comment-amount">
    <span class="amount pull-right">kr3,584.00</span>
</p>
```

How can i get this in to a jQuery variable..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Jquery `attr()`.

```js
var result = $('.cart-btn').attr("onclick")
console.log(result);

var re = /'(.*?)'/g;
var [a,b,c] = result.match(re);

console.log(a, b, c);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="cart-btn remove text-muted small" onclick="removeCart('89', '7647966b7343c29048673252e490f736', '0');"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></a>
<a class="name-image" onclick="openMenuOptions('89', '7647966b7343c29048673252e490f736');">
<span class="name">
    <span class="quantity">28 × </span>rum ‘n’ beat</span>
</a>
<p class="comment-amount">
    <span class="amount pull-right">kr3,584.00</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Updated the solution to use jquery `attr()`

Comment: removeCart('89', '7647966b7343c29048673252e490f736', '0');

now i want this value in variableslike;

var a=89;
var b=7647966b7343c29048673252e490f736;
and 
varc =0;

Comment: hassan immam u der ??

Comment: Updated the solution, just use regex and `split(',')`

Comment: trim it using trim() function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152433/discussion-between-hassan-imam-and-arushi).